# In repo workflow, what does it mean when my git branch and origin branch don't match?

Tags: git, repo

When I do `git status` I see something like this:

```
On branch feature/my_new_feature
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I'm using `repo`, and I kicked off this feature with `repo start feature/my_new_feature`, but I was expecting it to be based on `origin/feature/feature_release`, which is the branch we do our development on, and I hoped using `repo` meant I wouldn't have to jump into `git` to patch up basic things like branches...

We're all a bit new with `repo` here, so there's a good chance the project has been set up wrongly; where's the best place to start looking?

Comment: If I read the code correctly : setting the env var `REPO_TRACE=1` should give you some insight on what git commands are run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest file, the project has a default or specified revision or upstream. In your case, it's `develop`. `repo sync` is nearly equivalent to `git checkout  --detach <revision>` and it leads to detached HEAD. `repo start feature/my_new_feature` creates a named branch `feature/my_new_feature` from `<revision>` and sets `origin/develop` as its upstream, equivalent to `git checkout -b feature/my_new_feature origin/develop && git branch -u origin/develop`.

If you expect the upstream in `git status` to be `origin/feature/feature_release`, you should either specify the project's attribute `revision` or `upstream` in the manifest file as `feature/feature_release`, or use `git checkout -b feature/my_new_feature origin/feature/feature_release && git branch -u origin/feature/feature_release` in the repository. In the former way `feature/feature_release` should already exist in the remote repository, and in the latter `origin/feature/feature_release` should already exist in the local repository.